# Activemq embedded broker Error when trying to start

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

```
ERROR org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService - Failed to start Apache ActiveMQ ([localhost, null], java.io.IOException: org/apache/activemq/store/NoLocalSubscriptionAware)

INFO  org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService - Apache ActiveMQ 5.9.1 (localhost, null) is shutting down

INFO  org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector - Connector tcp://localhost:61616 stopped

WARN  org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagementContext - Failed to start JMX connector Cannot bind to URL [rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi]: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: jmxrmi [Root exception is java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException: jmxrmi]. Will restart management to re-create JMX connector, trying to remedy this issue.
```

The code I am trying to use is

```
BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
TransportConnector connector = new TransportConnector();
connector.setUri(new URI("tcp://localhost:61616"));
broker.addConnector(connector);
broker.start();
```

I am getting exception at start() method. I am deploying this on server not in my computer.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to say what is wrong given the limited information but one thing I'd check is that there isn't already a broker running on that server as it looks like something is at least sitting on the JMX port already.  You could check in the broker log to see if the broker logs any additional information on the error.